# Include python library using `import library name` and `from library name import *`

Tags: python

In the two following statements:

1. `import base64`
2. `from base64 import *`

since both would import the complete library yet we need to write `base64.b64encode()` for first case (to call b64encode() function from base64 library) and using the same for second case, we get a

`NameError: name 'base64' is not defined`.

For the second case `b64encode()` is used to call the function.

If they import the library completely then what causes this difference.

NOTE: base64 library is used only as an example.
EDIT: I was hoping for an explanation to why this happens and not which is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

`import module` imports the module/package, so it's available via `module`.

If you use `from module import *`, everything which is **within** the module/package, will be imported to the (let's call it) global namespace. Thus `module` itself is not imported.

Please consider some basic research when asking (the next) questions, this one has already been answered like a zillion times.

Comment: *this one has already been answered like a zillion times.* better skip the answer and vote to close as duplicate then :-)

Comment: I was one of the first voters to close, however I could not resist to spend one minute ;-) You know: there's someone wrong on the internet!!!